# Test Flight iphone app crashed with Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, testflight

I have developed an using react native with expo and after testing , it worked well without issue on simualtor using expo go. But after creating an beta app using testflight, it creashed after loading app. i am not able to understand log .. written as Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

attached log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: ParrotProjectv2 [647]

Triggered by Thread:  7

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x197284cb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 164
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x19031c3d0 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1047bede8 0x1046cc000 + 994792
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1972ec35c -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 188
4   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046fdd14 0x1046cc000 + 204052
5   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046fdf88 0x1046cc000 + 204680
6   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046d84dc 0x1046cc000 + 50396
7   ParrotProjectv2                        0x104701e98 0x1046cc000 + 220824
8   ParrotProjectv2                        0x104701e04 0x1046cc000 + 220676
9   ParrotProjectv2                        0x104701fd0 0x1046cc000 + 221136
10  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046dd580 0x1046cc000 + 71040
11  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046dd5e8 0x1046cc000 + 71144
12  ParrotProjectv2                        0x10471611c 0x1046cc000 + 303388
13  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1047189e4 0x1046cc000 + 313828
14  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046edde4 0x1046cc000 + 138724
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e74a320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e74beac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e753534 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e7540a4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e75ecdc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9ddc _pthread_wqthread + 288
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b7c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623aca4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d624db74 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d624de4c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623b1e8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1972f4024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1972f5250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1972fa3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   GraphicsServices                       0x1d281035c GSEventRunModal + 164
8   UIKitCore                              0x199686f58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9   UIKitCore                              0x199686bbc UIApplicationMain + 340
10  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1046d0b1c 0x1046cc000 + 19228
11  dyld                                   0x1b682cdec start + 2220

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623aca4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d624db74 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d624de4c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623b1e8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1972f4024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1972f5250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1972fa3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x191572fb4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x191572e9c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x1997b9cc8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 416
10  Foundation                             0x19158c524 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70ba6b8 _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 name:  com.facebook.react.JavaScript
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623aca4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d624db74 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d624de4c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623b1e8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1972f4024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1972f5250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1972fa3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1047d0c78 0x1046cc000 + 1068152
8   Foundation                             0x19158c524 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70ba6b8 _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 3 name:  hades
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623b578 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70c1078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a58d4ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   hermes                                 0x105028ca8 0x104f0c000 + 1166504
4   hermes                                 0x105028a5c 0x104f0c000 + 1165916
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70ba6b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 4 name:  hermes-chrome-inspector-conn
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623b578 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70c1078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a58d4ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1048d8530 0x1046cc000 + 2147632
4   ParrotProjectv2                        0x104891f6c 0x1046cc000 + 1859436
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70ba6b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:  hermes-inspector
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623b578 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70c1078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   libc++.1.dylib                         0x1a58d4ef8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   ParrotProjectv2                        0x1048d8530 0x1046cc000 + 2147632
4   ParrotProjectv2                        0x104891f6c 0x1046cc000 + 1859436
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70ba6b8 _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.AsyncLocalStorageQueue
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d623c678 write + 8
1   Foundation                             0x1915b986c _NSWriteToFileDescriptorWithProgress + 200
2   Foundation                             0x1915d44b0 ___NSWriteDataToFileWithExtendedAttributes_block_invoke + 72
3   Foundation                             0x19157f874 -[NSData(NSData) enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:] + 120
4   Foundation                             0x19159ddac _NSWriteDataToFileWithExtendedAttributes + 624
5   Foundation                             0x1915fb400 writeStringToURLOrPath + 188
6   ParrotProjectv2                        0x104789b84 0x1046cc000 + 777092
7   ParrotProjectv2                        0x10478addc 0x1046cc000 + 781788
8   CoreFoundation                         0x1972edc04 __invoking___ + 148
9   CoreFoundation                         0x19729bcb4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
10  CoreFoundation                         0x19729b6cc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
11  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1047eec1c 0x1046cc000 + 1190940
12  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1047f0c6c 0x1046cc000 + 1199212
13  ParrotProjectv2                        0x1047f08bc 0x1046cc000 + 1198268
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e74a320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e74beac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e753534 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e7540a4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e75ecdc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9ddc _pthread_wqthread + 288
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b7c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7 name:   Dispatch queue: expo.modules.AsyncFunctionQueue
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1d6241578 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70c0118 pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x19e7ac178 abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1f6ffebf8 abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1f6fee444 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x190321ea4 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1f6ffdfbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1f6ffdf60 std::terminate() + 56
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e74bec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e753534 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 668
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e7540a4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x19e75ecdc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9ddc _pthread_wqthread + 288
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f70b9b7c start_wqthread + 8
```